# Range and kernel of linear transformation $T: M_n(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$, $T(A) =trace(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Question: Given $T: M_n(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ is linear transformation such that $T(A) =trace(A)$,  where $A$ is n×n matrix. then find range, kernel, rank and nullity above linear transformation.

My attempt:

\begin{align} \operatorname{ker}(T)&= \{ A \in M_n(\mathbb{R}) | T(A) = 0 \}
\\&= \{ A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})| a_{11}+ a_{22}+...+ a_{nn}= 0\} \end{align}

So clearly $a_{11}$ is entry in matrix $A$ which can be expressed as linear combinations of $a_{22},...,a_{nn}$ so $nullity(T) = 1$

But then by rank nullity theorem we get $rank(T) = n^2 - 1$

But if I calculate $\operatorname{range}(T)$ then I saw something different!!

$\operatorname{Range}(T) = \operatorname{span}\{T(A_1),....,T(A_{n^2})\}$

Where $\{A_1, ....A_{n^2}\}$ is standard basis for $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ 
That is for eg. $A_1$ is matrix whose $a_{11}$ entry is 1 & $A_2$ is matrix whose $a_{12}$ entry is 1 and so on etc.

Then, \begin{align} \operatorname{Range}(T)&= \operatorname{span}\{ tr(A_1) , tr(A_2),\ldots ,tr(A_{n^2})\} \\
&=\operatorname{span}\{1, 0, 0, \ldots (n \text{ times }), 1,0, \ldots, (n \text{ times }), 1,....\} 
\\& = \operatorname{span}\{1\}\end{align}

So than $\operatorname{rank}(T) = 1$ which is wrong! 
I don't understand where I am wrong.
Please help me.

Comment: What is $R$?  Depending on what $R$ is, your question may be a total nonsense.

Comment: Thanks to all. Got it

Answer (score 2):

The $n^2-n$ elements $a_{ij}$ where $i \ne j$ are all arbitrary. And the $n$ elements $a_{ii}$ are related by one equation, which means $n-1$ of them are arbitrary. So the nullity should be $n^2-1$.

Answer (score 2):

What's the problem? The range of $T$ is $\operatorname\{1\}$, which is equal to $\mathbb R$. So, $\operatorname{rank}T=1$ and $\dim\ker T=n^2-1$.

I am assuming that $R$ means $\mathbb R$, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a linear system in $n^2$ variable where the variables are $a_{11}, a_{12}, \ldots, a_{nn}$.

If you have a single constraint.

$$a_{11}+a_{22}+a_{33}+\ldots +a_{nn}=0$$

There is exactly one pivot element, the rest can be treated as free variables.

Hence the nullity is $n^2-1$ while the rank is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your second argument is the valid one: $\mathrm{rank}\,T=1$.

And, the formula you wrote up for $\ker T$ is also valid, and these altogether answer the question.